# Getting a list of arrays into a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a list of arrays in Python: `[[0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1]]`. I would like to make this list of arrays into a Pandas dataframe, with each array being a row. Is there a way to do this quickly and easily in Python? I tried `values = np.split(values, len(values))` to split the list of arrays into multiple arrays (well, I tried). And then tried to create a dataframe with `df = pd.DataFrame(values)`. But this is where my error came from. I got a "must pass 2-d input" error message. Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it? Or an easier way to go about this? Thanks!

Comment: But you show a tuple of lists right now...

Comment: Did `df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1]])` not work?

Comment: ...which would work fine in pd.DataFrame()

Comment: Are you sure you have imported in correctly ? ie import pandas as pd? pd.DataFrame() should work

Answer (score 5):

No need to do all that splitting, etc. If you have it as a list of lists that is two dimensional (meaning all rows have the same number of elements), you can simply pass it to the `DataFrame` constructor:

```
data = [[0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1]]
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

generating the expected:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(data)
   0  1  2  3
0  0  1  0  1
1  1  0  1  1
2  0  1  1  1
```